# google chart and jquery highchart

Tags: highcharts, google-visualization

My UI screens currently use jQuery datatables. I need to add chart feature to some of the screens. I have worked on some samples that utilizes [google chart APIs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start) and some that are rendered using jQuery [highchart](http://highcharttable.org). My first inclination is to use jQuery highchart since all my screens render data tables using jQuery datatables. Is there a technical reason, difference or performance orientation that I choose one over the other. I have been researching this but did not find a concrete reason to bias towards one of the options.

Comment: It always helps if things are asked and answered to the point. The question was down voted with a reason that its not useful or show research/efforts. I could have mentioned everything I researched but that will not help getting an answer to this question (because I already know what I researched).
1. Google charts are free to use whereas highchart offers both free and paid (commercial) versions. [Source](https://www.similartech.com/compare/google-charts-vs-highcharts)

Comment: Downvote to a question based on the reasoning that no research was shown does not make sense. It depends on the question. I would have shown code snippets with error responses if it was a programming question. The question here is a category of selecting a technology over others. I could have copy pasted contents I researched with corresponding source links but let me know how would it really help the experts to answer my question. I did research lot of contents and that is why I explicitly mentioned this statement.Downvote is not an issue but the tendency is so I thought to explicitly mention

Answer (score 1):

I've diligently used both, and the way it stands today, highcharts just has more to offer, and documentation is superb. You can make that decision yourself by looking at the charts gallery for [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) and [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo). I personally also think Google Charts has a steeper learning curve. They have two very distinct versions and just more clumsy getting it running. Lastly, Highcharts has animation by default.

You can use jQuery datatables for both though.